# Neo4j IndexEntryConflictException when CREATE new node

Tags: java, database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

**Neo4j Enterprise 4.4.7**

**Causal cluster with 3 nodes (1 leader + 2 followers)**

**Data: 10M+ Nodes and 10M+ Rels**

It seems that our cluster has entered a corrupted state. We have a daily process in place that updates our database with new data.

Since last Saturday it started failing.

After investigating the issue it looks like **the database is keeping a reference to a deleted node** (??)

[image: Neo4j browser error]

This seems to happen only when executed from the shell script batched query. If I execute the CREATE query manually it won't fail

**Some other SO questions that I think are related to this one:**

[Neo4j 2.0 unique constraint error "node already exists" when it does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937286/neo4j-2-0-unique-constraint-error-node-already-exists-when-it-does-not)

[neo4j constraint deleted node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771577/neo4j-constraint-deleted-node)